# Why sample size is coming as double with statsmodels package in Python

Tags: python, statistics

I am using following code to find sample size for given means and SD in 2 groups:

```
from statsmodels.stats.power import TTestIndPower
power = 0.8
alpha = 0.05
mean1 = 10; sd1 = 7
mean2 = 17; sd2 = 7
diffmean = mean2-mean1
pooled_sd = np.sqrt(sd1**2 + sd2**2)
es = diffmean / pooled_sd
res = TTestIndPower().solve_power(effect_size=es, 
           power=power, alpha=alpha, nobs1=None)
print(res)
```

Output is:

```
32.38441093768741
```

On [Statsmodels help page](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.power.TTestIndPower.solve_power.html) it says, that the sample size returned (nobs1) is for one (first) group.

However, I checked sample size with same means and SD values at [OpenEpi online sample size calculator](https://www.openepi.com/SampleSize/SSMean.htm):

I got following result:

[image]

Here it clearly states that 32 is sample size for both groups combined and not for one group.

I also tested same problem with `pwr` package in R as detailed on [this page](https://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html):

```
> pwr.t.test(n = , d = (17-10)/sqrt(7^2+7^2), 
    sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.8, type = "two.sample")
```

where d is effect size: (difference in means)/ pooled_sd

The output was:

```
     Two-sample t test power calculation 

              n = 32.38441
              d = 0.7071068
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.8
    alternative = two.sided

NOTE: n is number in *each* group
```

It clearly states that 32 is number for each group (hence total sample size needed is 64).

Where is the problem? Which of these sites is correct?

Comment: my guess is that effect size assumes population sd and not pooled sd of diff, `es = diffmean / sd1` (statsmodels unit test that verify correctness against R pwr use predefined effect size)

Comment: I have added R code also using pwr package. So OpenEpi site calculations are not correct?

Comment: https://www.socscistatistics.com/effectsize/default3.aspx uses pooled sd but divided by two. All codes are correct but with the appropriate definition of effect size, which is computed internally in OpenEpi and another calculator that I checked.

Comment: I think error was that I was not dividing by 2 for pooled SD. If you think this is correct and enter this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

statsmodels and pwr use Cohen's d as a measure of effect size. This is difference in mean divided by some estimate of the population standard deviation.

```
Cohen's d = (M2 - M1) ⁄ SDpooled
SDpooled = sqrt((SD1**2 + SD2**2) ⁄ 2)
```

see for example https://www.socscistatistics.com/effectsize/default3.aspx

The estimate of the population variance is a weighted average of the individual standard deviation. The weights need to add up to 1.

In the example of the question a division by 2 is missing in the pooled sd computation.

Comment: Pl see this also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474661/is-result-of-this-simplified-formula-for-sample-size-for-one-group-or-for-both-g